# Matrix multiplication MPI

Tags: c++, matrix, mpi, matrix-multiplication

At the university, I was asked a laboratory for parallel programming: parallelize the multiplication of matrices. I wrote an algorithm similar to the example, but the implementation provides a breakpoint. Tell me, please, what can I fix?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
const int N=4; 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int r,q,myid,numprocs;
    int i0;
    int *b,*c,*loc_a,*loc_c;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    MPI_Status status;
    q=N/numprocs;
    b=new int [N*N];
    c=new int [N*N];
    loc_c=new int[N*N];
    loc_a=new int[q];
    for(int i=0;i<N*N;i++)     {
        c[i]=0;      loc_c[i]=0;     
    }     
    if(myid==0)     {
        for (int j = 0; j<numprocs; j++) {
            for (r = 0; r<q*N; r++) {
                loc_a[r] = 1; 
            }        
            MPI_Send(&loc_a[0], q*N, MPI_INT, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        }      
        for (int i = 0; i<N*N; i++) { 
            b[i] = 1; 
        }        
    }     
    MPI_Recv(&loc_a[0], q*N, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    for (r = 0; r<N; r++) {
        MPI_Bcast(&b[r*N], N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        i0 = myid*q;
        for (int i = 0; i<q; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
                loc_c[r*N + i0] += loc_a[i*N + j] * b[r*N + j]; 
            }      
            i0++; 
        }     
        MPI_Reduce(loc_c, c, N*N, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    }     
    if (myid == 0) {
        FILE *f = fopen("result.txt", "w");
        for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
                fprintf(f, "%d\t", c[j*N + i]); 
            }       
            fprintf(f, "\n"); 
        }     
        fclose(f); 
    }
return 0; 
MPI_Finalize(); 
}
```

Comment: debug the code, at least tell us the line

Comment: job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Send(buf=0x00277FE8, count=16, MPI_INT, dest=0, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
DEADLOCK: attempting to send a message to the local process without a prior matching receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got seems pretty straightforward:

You are calling blocking MPI_SEND on a process with itself as the target (`myid == 0`and`j == 0`) without calling a non-blocking RECV first, meaning your process will infinitely wait for itself to receive the message before continuing, causing a Deadlock.

You have multiple options here, depending on your goals:

1. call non-blocking recv first
2. do not use MPI_Send to send to itself (check if `my_id == j` and don't send if true)

Comment: Thanks for useful answer, first choice is working.